# mysql auto increment value is not getting updated sequentially

Tags: mysql

I have table with Auto increment column as shown below.

```
CREATE TABLE `garment_master2` (
  `GARMENT_ID2` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `GARMENT_NAME1` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`GARMENT_ID2`),
  KEY `NDX_gar_name` (`GARMENT_NAME1`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

when rows are inserted one by one then auto increment values are sequential. But if I insert multiple rows at a time using insert into command then final auto increment value is more than `GARMENT_ID2` value i.e if 12 rows are inserted then `GARMENT_ID2` value is 12 and auto increment value is 16.

Please help me to understand why auto increment value is not correctly set.

Comment: Instead of auto increment, try Identity(1,1)

Comment: To auto increment primary key, you have to use identity .. for more info see this http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_autoincrement.asp

Answer (score -1):

Try This

```
CREATE TABLE `garment_master2` (
  `GARMENT_ID2` int NOT NULL IDENTITY(1,1),
  `GARMENT_NAME1` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`GARMENT_ID2`),
  KEY `NDX_gar_name` (`GARMENT_NAME1`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

Instead of Auto increment, use Identity.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But this solution is not working in mysql 5.5.16. I am getting syntax error while creating the table.

Comment: have you deleted any record after inserting?

Comment: No delete operations are done .after creating the table i am inserting data by selecting data from another table.